# Binding to an object from both route and query string for a GET method

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I've been playing around with web api's in 2.2 and have no problems with post methods with objects or get methods with primitives. My issue is I would like to bind to a model object from a get method from a value in the route and a query string value simultaneously.

So basically from the code below I would like to bind to a simple object. If you imagine the url is:

http://localhost:9999/api/Values/{Firstname}?{Surname}=Bob

I've tried decorating the model object and received 415 responses which seemed bizarre

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace apitest.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        // GET api/values/5
        [HttpGet("{Firstname}")]
        public ActionResult<string> Get(Person person)
        {
            return "value";
        }
    }
}

namespace apitest
{
    public class Person
    {
        public string Firstname { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Obviously the example is trivial and nonsensical but basically I just want to map the Firstname and Surname from the route/querystring tp the Firstname/Surname properties on the Person object. Do I have to write custom model binders? If so, any great examples out there?

Comment: Try to  annotate the Person parameter with [FromBody]: `HttpGet("{Firstname}")]
        public ActionResult<string> Get([FromBody]Person person)
        {
            return "value";
        }`

Comment: Hi that returns the following {"":["The input was not valid."]}. Also wouldn't FromBody only be relevant for posts?

Answer (score 6):

It's been a while, but maybe someone having the same problem in ASP.NET Core 3.1  will end up here, so I'll leave my answer :)

Annotating person parameter with [FromQuery] attribute and Firstname property with [FromRoute] attribute does the trick.

So it should look like this:

```
namespace apitest.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        // GET api/values/5
        [HttpGet("{Firstname}")]
        public ActionResult<string> Get([FromQuery] Person person)
        {
            return "value";
        }
    }
}

namespace apitest
{
    public class Person
    {
        [FromRoute]
        public string Firstname { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your issue, it is caused by `SuppressInferBindingSourcesForParameters`.

```
//
// Summary:
//     Options used to configure behavior for types annotated with Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiControllerAttribute.
public class ApiBehaviorOptions : IEnumerable<ICompatibilitySwitch>, IEnumerable
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets or sets a value that determines if model binding sources are inferred for
    //     action parameters on controllers annotated with Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiControllerAttribute
    //     is suppressed.
    //     When enabled, the following sources are inferred: Parameters that appear as route
    //     values, are assumed to be bound from the path (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.BindingSource.Path).
    //     Parameters of type Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IFormFile and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IFormFileCollection
    //     are assumed to be bound from form. Parameters that are complex (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelMetadata.IsComplexType)
    //     are assumed to be bound from the body (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.BindingSource.Body).
    //     All other parameters are assumed to be bound from the query.
    public bool SuppressInferBindingSourcesForParameters { get; set; }
```

Configure this value in `Startup.cs` like

```
services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
.ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options => {
    options.SuppressInferBindingSourcesForParameters = true;
});
```